# Converting .arff file to .csv using Python

Tags: python, csv, arff

I have a file "LMD.rh.arff" which I am trying to convert to .csv file using the following code-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import arff


# Read in .arff file-
data = arff.loadarff("LMD.rh.arff")
```

But this last line of code gives me the error-

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 data = arff.loadarff("LMD.rp.arff")
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py in
>   loadarff(f)
>       539         ofile = open(f, 'rt')
>       540     try:
>   --> 541         return _loadarff(ofile)
>       542     finally:
>       543         if ofile is not f:  # only close what we opened
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py in
>   _loadarff(ofile)
>       627     a = generator(ofile)
>       628     # No error should happen here: it is a bug otherwise
>   --> 629     data = np.fromiter(a, descr)
>       630     return data, meta
>       631
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in
>   position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> In [6]: data = arff.loadarff("LMD.rh.arff")
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 data = arff.loadarff("LMD.rh.arff")
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py in
>   loadarff(f)
>       539         ofile = open(f, 'rt')
>       540     try:
>   --> 541         return _loadarff(ofile)
>       542     finally:
>       543         if ofile is not f:  # only close what we opened
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py in
>   _loadarff(ofile)
>       627     a = generator(ofile)
>       628     # No error should happen here: it is a bug otherwise
>   --> 629     data = np.fromiter(a, descr)
>       630     return data, meta
>       631
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in
>   position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

You can download the file [arff_file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7bo44g1xu3oli7/LMD.rh.arff?dl=0)

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
path_to_directory="./"
files = [arff for arff in os.listdir(path_to_directory) if arff.endswith(".arff")]

def toCsv(content): 
    data = False
    header = ""
    newContent = []
    for line in content:
        if not data:
            if "@attribute" in line:
                attri = line.split()
                columnName = attri[attri.index("@attribute")+1]
                header = header + columnName + ","
            elif "@data" in line:
                data = True
                header = header[:-1]
                header += '\n'
                newContent.append(header)
        else:
            newContent.append(line)
    return newContent

# Main loop for reading and writing files
for zzzz,file in enumerate(files):
    with open(path_to_directory+file , "r") as inFile:
        content = inFile.readlines()
        name,ext = os.path.splitext(inFile.name)
        new = toCsv(content)
        with open(name+".csv", "w") as outFile:
            outFile.writelines(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the error trace

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Your error suggests you have some encoding problem with the file. Consider first opening the file with the correct encoding and then loading it to the arff loader

```
import codecs
import arff

file_ = codecs.load('LMD.rh.arff', 'rb', 'utf-8') # or whatever encoding you have 
arff.load(file_) # now this should be fine
```

For reference see [here](https://pythonhosted.org/liac-arff/#unicode)

Comment: when I try the line "codecs.load()", it says: AttributeError: module 'codecs' has no attribute 'load'

Comment: I tried the following code- f = codecs.open("LMD.rh.arff", "r", "utf-8")                            data = arff.loadarff(f)     However, the same error is generated